# How to set Jasmine global variables as coming from the window?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine

How can I add to `Jasmine` global variables for unit testing?

For example, I have function `foo` on window, and the testes code relies on that function.

And no, using this specific function as a pure function is not possible in this case.. it must be some mock for the window object..

Comment: Could you add some example code?

Comment: you would do this by injecting some window service that wraps the native window object, use that exclusively to access the window object, and then mocking that service in your test